# Javascript promise with angular http call not hydrating object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I know that I have done this before, but somehow it is not working

So I have an Angular controller which calls an Angular service and sends in and returns data

In the promise the console.log spits out the data, but i thought with `.then` it should persist the data outside the .then , right?

```
   var receipt = this;

    receipt.airportCode = {};
    var xx = "";

    airportCodeService.getAirlineFromCarrierId('GH')
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            xx = result;
            receipt.airportCode = result;
        })
        .catch(function () {
            console.log('problem');
        });

        console.log('xx',xx)   // displays only  "xx"
```

I get > Object {}  // with the console.log of the receipt.airportCode outside of .then

Comment: Yes it will persist outside, but the value won't be set until the method call is done executing and done setting the value you want to check. You are checking the value xx too early (it's not excuted in sequence - it's parallel and the last line in your code is not the last line to run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Anurag, asynchronous calls are... asynchronous and processing the next commands are not halted until the asynchronous call has completed. When calling a method that returns a `promise`, the only way to know if the code in the `.then` block was run, is to check if the `promise` was resolved.

You are already checking and setting stuff in your `.then` block, but this block will most likely not have been called/completed when you `console.log` the result on your last line.

This is a good thing. The whole idea of asynchronous calls is to be able to do several things in parallel or to not worry about 'when what happens'.

When you do have to worry about wether or not an asynchronous call has completed, you just have to check that promise.

The obvious solution is to move your console.log into the `.then` block. If you have some code you want executed after the promise has completed, this is the place to do so. You could also keep a reference to the promise when calling the `.getAirlineFromCarrierId` method, and then later wait for it to complete.

```
var xx;
var promise = airportCodeService.getAirlineFromCarrierId('GH').then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    xx = result;
    receipt.airportCode = result;
    doStuff(); // This is one way to not clutter your .then with lines of code
}).catch(function () {
    console.log('problem');
});

promise.then(function () { // you can ask your promise any number of times later, if you keep the reference to the promise
    console.log('xx',xx);
})

function doStuff() {
    console.log('xx', xx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `airportCodeService.getAirlineFromCarrierId` ,`.then` promise does not execute immediately. nodejs will execute next statement i.e. `console.log('xx',xx)` .By this time no response from `airportCodeService.getAirlineFromCarrierId` has come. By using promises, it doesn't make asynchronous operation synchronous.

You can try different ways to make it persistent.

If you want to console.log, you can use a function to do that,

```
    var receipt = this;

    receipt.airportCode = {};
    var xx = "";

    function consoleData(data){
       console.log(data);
    }

    airportCodeService.getAirlineFromCarrierId('GH')
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            xx = result;
            receipt.airportCode = result;
            consoleData(xx);
        })
        .catch(function () {
            console.log('problem');
        });
```

Or you can define a function to which changes the value of variable.

```
    var receipt = this;

    receipt.airportCode = {};
    var xx = "";

    function changexx(data){
       //do something here
       console.log("xx changed",xx);
    }

    airportCodeService.getAirlineFromCarrierId('GH')
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            changexx(result);
            receipt.airportCode = result;
            consoleData(xx);
        })
        .catch(function () {
            console.log('problem');
        });
```

You can look into how to attach changeListener to objects. But that will be a bit of overkill.

Comment: What is a better way to get persistence from this data?

Comment: @PeterGrainger terrible 'advice' with the setTimeout as i'm pretty sure OP is adopting this solution now...

Comment: I was just trying to prove that the value was persisted.  Just not immediately, not that he should use it in prod.  Deleted to avoid any misunderstandings.

Answer (score -1):

try to define a scope-variable for this.

```
$scope.xx = "";

airportCodeService.getAirlineFromCarrierId('GH')
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.xx = result;
            receipt.airportCode = result;
        })
        .catch(function () {
            console.log('problem');
        });

        console.log('xx',$scope.xx)
```

Attention: you might have to inject $scope in your controller

Comment: Is this considered decent practice?    I'm just thinking that while I am leveraging/using the angular framework  -  I know that promises are with javascript and jquery and if there was no $scope available  - what would you do ?

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck  - any other solution ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller i posted two solutions, if neither suits you, then we're missing some information (you might need to provide a larger example/fiddle)